# after click current Tab does not show pop up

Tags: jquery

I have a set of tabs,One of them contains a button when I click on it. I can edit the information but if you want to go out to another tab, I can see Pop up .I have a problem in When you click on the same tab that have the button and exit for another tab, the popup does not appear!

---

```
let editButtonHandler = false;
  let showPopUp = false;
  let canMove = true;
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    //hide Cancel Button.
    $("#CancelBtn").hide();

    $("#editBtnProfile").click(function()
    {
      //click on Edit and show Cancel.
      if (showPopUp)
      {
        editButtonHandler = !editButtonHandler;
        $("#CancelBtn").show();
      }
    });
    $("#CancelBtn").click(function()
    {
      //click on Cancel after click on edit.
      if (showPopUp ) {
        editButtonHandler = false;
        showPopUp = false;
      }
    });
    $("#navTabs").click(function()
    {
      if (showPopUp && editButtonHandler)
      {
        disabledEditBtn();
        disableInput();
        $("#CancelBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
        canMove = confirm("You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to continue?");
        $('#editBtnProfile').text('Edit Profile');
      }
    });
    $('#navTabs li').click(function(event){
      if(event.currentTarget.id === 'biotab') {
        showPopUp = true;
        editButtonHandler = false;
      } else if (!editButtonHandler){
        showPopUp = true;
        $("#CancelBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
      }
    });
  });
```